# iOS Dispatch Async Crash

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, sprite-kit

I working on a sprite kit game. Well, I am trying to load the sprites in the background while a loading screen stays on the screen. I have the function below to to it. It does what I want but "sometimes" it crashes. Same code, why does it crash or not crash? I tested on iPhone 5, iPhone 6+ and iPad 2. The function crashes not that much on iPhone 5 and 6+ but it crashes a lot on iPad 2. Thanks in advance. This is the function;

```
func loadingScreen() {
    //Initialize loading sprite.
    let loadBg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "loadBg.png");
    loadBg.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height);
    loadBg.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2);
    loadBg.zPosition = 10;
    self.addChild(loadBg);
    let loadBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "load1.png");
    loadBar.size = CGSize(width: self.size.width/3, height: (self.size.width/3)*0.20);
    loadBar.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height*0.1);
    loadBar.zPosition = 11;
    self.addChild(loadBar);
    var loadAni:[SKTexture] = [];
    for index in 1...17 {
        loadAni.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "load\(index).png"));
    }
    loadBar.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(loadAni, timePerFrame: 0.01)));
    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        // Codes.
        self.startGame()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            // Codes after loading.
            self.objectSlider.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.moveByX(-self.size.width/5.8, y: 0, duration: 0.5)))
            self.printPlayer()
            self.isGameOver = false;
            loadBg.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.2),SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
            loadBar.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.2),SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
        })

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful and know exactly what you are doing with threads. Your crash is likely a thread safety issue, but there is no way to know based on what you have posted. You will need to start over and really think through what you need to do and how use of threads impacts that. From what I can see, you will get no benefit at all from loading images to be used as textures in a background thread since loading of image data gets put off until the image data is actually accessed anyway. The most likely cause of your crash is that call to startGame() from a background thread, but honestly there is no way to tell from what you have posted. When it comes to threads, if you do something crazy and it crashes, then don't do that.

Comment: Well basically, how can I run a function in background while a loading animation runs in the main thread? Then how can I  remove the loading animation when function in the background is completed?

Comment: You can't. At least not like you are attempting to do it. Loading a PNG image means that the compressed data is decoded into memory. That is a huge huge inflation of the data and that takes up a massive amount of memory. You cannot just "load it in the background" because there is not enough memory of the device to cache all that image data in memory. You have a basic concept problem. For example, to see a solution for this same issue as it relates to loading OpenGL textures, see this example: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post7_load_opengl_textures_with_alpha_channel_on_ios/index.html

Comment: Oh I think I understand. Can you prefer me another way to make a loading screen for my game?

Comment: Just to make it clear, what the example I mention above does is decode each frame of an animation as a framebuffer and then each framebuffer is written to a single large file as a background process (this does not consume all memory on the device). Then, each already decoded frame is streamed from the file into the currently active framebuffer one at a time with minimal CPU usage.